# How to resolve an alignment issue with CSS

Tags: html, css

I' having the issue showed in the next snippet and have no idea what should I do to make it right-aligned in one column with text next to it.

```css
/* Personal Details */

.personal-info {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.personal-info li span {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.personal-info li p {
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.detail-icon {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="personal-info">
  <li>
    <p>
      <span class="">Name</span> Jonny be Good
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <span class="">Age</span> 34
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <span class="">Location</span> Copenhagen DK
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <span class="">Degree</span> BSc
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <span class="">Telephone</span> 1234567890
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <span class="">Email</span>
      <a href="mailto:somewhere@gmx.com">somewhere@gmx.com</a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The circles are there because I will put there an image icon instead of the text title of the section like name Jon will be icon Jon and so on.

I'm unable to find out how to align those in the right way and I stuck with it and also make the text to be on the center-aligned next to the circle

Comment: How do you need it to look? Could you possibly provide a sketch?

Comment: Will you consider not using float to achieve this?

Comment: It's because you float the circle which is overflowing into the next row so the next circle has to start from where the previous one finishes - try changing the line height to be the size of the circle or add `clear:left` to the li.  Or better still, don't use float - you shouldn't need to anymore with css3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s difficult to understand from the description how it should be, so I’ll try to guess

Something like this?

https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/RwbxqZG

```css
/* Personal Details */

.personal-info {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  list-style: none;
}

.personal-info li span {
  /* float: left; */
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  /* border: 1px solid #cdcdcd; */
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  /* height: 50px; */
  /* width: 50px; */
}

.personal-info li p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.detail-icon {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="personal-info">
  <li>
    <p>
      <img class="detail-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/858/536/354">
      <span> Jonny be Good</span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img class="detail-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/858/536/354">
      <span> 34</span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img class="detail-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/858/536/354">
      <span> Copenhagen DK</span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img class="detail-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/858/536/354">
      <span> BSc</span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img class="detail-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/858/536/354">
      <span> 1234567890</span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img class="detail-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/858/536/354">
      <a href="mailto:somewhere@gmx.com">somewhere@gmx.com</a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I need exactly thanks and that will work also with an img background in the span? Without that source you add in the html but as an image background in the css